# Build a standalone qt application with static libraries - configure command missing

Tags: qt, mingw, configure

I want to build a standalone QT application using MinGW.
See this link -> https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows

I could not take these steps, as the "configure"-command could not be found when I tried to execute it (despite having qt in the PATH).

I found out, that I needed the qt-source to build my own libraries, since the configure-command is only available in those. So I did that by downloading Qt5.12.0 from the archives (https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/5.12.0/ downloading the qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.12.0.exe file), but after insatlling that, I still couldn't find a configure command.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is the installer for Windows.

To get the sourcecode use one of the qt-everywhere archives in
https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/5.12.0/single/. I.e. https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/5.12.0/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.0.zip and unpack it.

Comment: Really? So I just downloaded the wrong thing? Wow, I feel stupid now. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The configuration script is part of the Qt source code, it is right there in the root of the Qt sources.

[image]

You can download the sources as an archive, you can also install them via the installer, although I do not recommend the latter, as it is very, very slow.

Then you need to build the Qt source code in a static configuration.

After that is done, you simply add this version of Qt in Creator, create a Kit that uses it, and then you simply use that kit when you want to produce a statically linked application.